# DenseVector to array list Pyspark ML

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have a variable `dense_vector` it will print out `DenseVector([0.0, 0.0, 0.9998])` when i print it

Is there a way to get only the array `[0.0, 0.0, 0.9998]`?

Comment: ```dense_vector.toArray()```
will give you an array.

Answer (score 1):

In your case - at least according to [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=densevector#pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector.values) I found - you should be able to access those values with `DenseVector.values`.

General answer:

The string representation of an object must not neccassarily reflect the object's content. The data could be stored as a list, tuple, dict, attribute, ... within the class instance, so your best bet is to look at the `__str__` / `__repr__` implementation and build the list yourself.

Or, if it's your own class, create a method that returns the list, or you could even sub-class the class and then add a method on your own class that returns the list.